# LCD Screen and Speaker

Tags: gpio

I am trying to make a simple alarm clock with a LCD screen and speaker.

I am loosely using [this tutorial from Adafruit](https://learn.adafruit.com/mini-mac-pi/circuit-diagram) as a reference, with the biggest difference being that I want to power everything **without** a portable battery. The problem is that the screen will take up all of the GPIO pins so I do not know how/where I would connect the amplifier to the Raspberry Pi?

Should I solder the speaker to the GPIO pins that the TFT screen has on it (20 I believe)? Or should I use some sort of breakout-board?

The parts I am using are :

- Amplifier: [Adafruit stereo 2.8W Class D Audio Amplifier](https://www.adafruit.com/product/1712)
- Speaker: [Adafruit 3" Diameter - 8 Ohm 1 Watt](https://www.adafruit.com/products/1313)
- Screen: [PiTFT Plus 480x320 3.5" TFT+Touchscreen for Raspberry Pi](https://www.adafruit.com/products/2441)

Answer (score 1):

From the specs for the PiTFT screen:

"The display uses the hardware SPI pins (SCK, MOSI, MISO, CE0, CE1) as well as GPIO #25 and #24. GPIO #18 can be used to PWM dim the backlight if you like. **All other GPIO are unused.** There's a 2x13 'classic Pi' connection GPIO header on the bottom, you can connect a 26-pin Pi GPIO cable to it to use any of the other pins as you like. The other GPIO are broken out into solder pads at the bottom, in case you want to use more of the GPIO."

So, yes, you can solder to the unused GPIO pins from the bottom.  The link you provided doesn't go to anything resembling your project.

Comment: Thanks! Just to be totally clear: are you saying I should solder the amplifier to the unused GPIO pins on the Raspberry Pi's bottom or should I solder it to the unused GPIO pins that the PiTFT screen's board has?